# Cannot unpack non-iterable object Django

Tags: python, django

So, I'm trying to filter a field's choices by the *created_by* attribute, which is an User instance gotten from the request when it was created.

After doing some research I found some explanations and followed them but I couldn't get the choices to actually appear at the form. Now I'm getting the error that Categoria Object isn't Iterable.

the Classes I used as a model to the Form:

```py
class Contato(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sobrenome = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    telefone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    data_criacao = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
    descricao = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(
        Categoria, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    mostrar = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    foto = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='fotos/%y/%m/%d')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome


class Categoria(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

this is the code from the Form I'm trying to modify

```py
class ContatoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contato
        exclude = ('created_by',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(ContatoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        category_choices = list(Categoria.objects.filter(
            created_by=self.user))

        self.fields['categoria'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=category_choices)
```

And this is the view I'm using this form at

```py
@login_required(redirect_field_name='login')
def dashboard(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form_contato = ContatoForm(user=request.user)
        form_categoria = CategoriaForm

        return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', {'form_contato': form_contato, 'form_categoria': form_categoria})
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\gabriel\codando\studying\django_learning\DjangoProj_agenda\accounts\views.py", line 107, in dashboard
    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', {'form_contato': form_contato, 'form_categoria': form_categoria})
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 994, in render
    return render_value_in_context(output, context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 973, in render_value_in_context
    value = str(value)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\html.py", line 376, in <lambda>
    klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 132, in __str__
    return self.as_table()
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 270, in as_table
    return self._html_output(
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 227, in _html_output
    output.append(normal_row % {
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\html.py", line 376, in <lambda>
    klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py", line 34, in __str__
    return self.as_widget()
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py", line 90, in as_widget
    attrs = self.build_widget_attrs(attrs, widget)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py", line 225, in build_widget_attrs
    if widget.use_required_attribute(self.initial) and self.field.required and self.form.use_required_attribute:
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 705, in use_required_attribute
    return use_required_attribute and first_choice is not None and self._choice_has_empty_value(first_choice)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 691, in _choice_has_empty_value
    value, _ = choice

Exception Type: TypeError at /accounts/dashboard/
Exception Value: cannot unpack non-iterable Categoria object
```

Comment: Insantiate the form object, i.e. `form_categoria = CategoriaForm()`. Also next time post the **whole error message** with **full traceback**.

Comment: The full traceback is *huge*, that's why I didn't post it, sorry :/ I'll add it to the post and try to use your help, thanks!

Comment: Even though I instanciated it, I keep getting the same error

Comment: Ok, the traceback explains it: See the docs for [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices). You are assigning a list of `Categoria` objects to it but it needs to be _"an iterable of 2-tuples"_. We don't see your `Categoria` class but try something like `choices=[(c.id, c.name) for c in category_choices]`.

Comment: Just added the Categoria Class to the post, I'm going to try that, thanks again

Comment: Now It works, thank you so much. I'm going to take a look at choices documentation. I started testing and studying Django this week.

Comment: Have a look at [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield), you should use it instead of choice field.